# Strange behaviour of jQuery attr() method

Tags: jquery

After digging the **[jQuery sources](http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js)** I still can't understand why the code like:

```
$("div").attr("someAttr", undefined);
```

returns *jQuery object* but not an *attribute value*, despite the fact that the second `value` argument is set as `undefined`.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5jn5D/.

Comment: Because you are passing two arguments, it acts like a setter(Even though the value is undefined). If you just need to get the value, try `$("div").attr("someAttr")`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2 as shown at `attr(attributeName,value)` blue header it returns jQuery cause its a setter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, because [`.attr("someAttr", undefined)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) (with 2 arguments) is a setter method, and thus returns the object for sake of chainability. Setting the argument to `undefined` or any other arbitrary value always yields the same effect. Why should a value be returned, if you know what the value is?

If you use `attr` as getter method (with only 1 argument) `.attr("someAttr")` it returns a string with the attribute value.

Line 2003 in the source explicitely checks for the length of the arguments:

```
return jQuery.access( this, jQuery.attr, name, value, arguments.length > 1 );
```

with the fifth argument being the `chainable` switch, returning true for `arguments > 1`.

Comment: While what you say is entirely true, it's clear that this is not answering the question at hand. He asked about the source, and specifically about the fact that the second value passed is undefined. He is asking why it treats it as a setter and not a getter. Maybe `how` would be more appropriate than `why`

Comment: @antishok what is so hard to understand about "Line 2003 in the source explicitely checks for the length of the arguments."?

Comment: Cristoph: It was hard to understand when it wasn't there, at the time I submitted my comment. about 20 seconds later I did see your edit appear :p

Comment: @antishok my edit: 15mins ago, your comment 14mins ago, so my edit was earlier:-p But i I hope my second edit clarifies this.

Comment: Regardless, Niko's answer was way earlier and is still far more relevant. Your answer is looking more and more like his with each edit

Comment: That is still no reason to downvote, since my answer is correct, but feel free to do as you like. (And 24mins < 22mins for sure)

Comment: I meant - his answer to the actual question. Let's stop. Downvote redacted. All happy

Answer (score 2):

It's due to this bit:

```
attr: function( name, value ) {
    return jQuery.access( this, jQuery.attr, name, value, arguments.length > 1 );
},

// ...

access: function( elems, fn, key, value, chainable, emptyGet, pass ) {
    // ..
    return chainable ? ...
}
```

Notice that the check whether the method was called as a getter or setter is not due to the value of "value", but just to the number of arguments:

```
arguments.length > 1
```

Comment: For some stupid reason I managed to think that `arguments.length > 1` is `false` in line `return chainable ? ...`. Now it is clear that it returns `elems`. Thanks!